# Deployment failed while installing a new war file in IBM WebSphere Application Server Community edition

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am getting the below error while installing the war file mentioned here.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0809_vamsi/0809_vamsi.html

Deployment Failed
Unable to create configuration for deployment
org.apache.geronimo.common.DeploymentException: Unable to create configuration for deployment
 at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.DeploymentContext.createTempConfiguration(DeploymentContext.java:149)
 at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.DeploymentContext.(DeploymentContext.java:129)
 at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.DeploymentContext.(DeploymentContext.java:109)
 at org.apache.geronimo.j2ee.deployment.EARContext.(EARContext.java:68)
 at org.apache.geronimo.j2ee.deployment.EARConfigBuilder.buildConfiguration(EARConfigBuilder.java:528)
 at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:255)
 at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:134)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.ReflectionMethodInvoker.invoke(ReflectionMethodInvoker.java:34)
 at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanOperation.invoke(GBeanOperation.java:124)
 at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.invoke(GBeanInstance.java:867)
 at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.invoke(BasicKernel.java:239)
 at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.plugin.local.AbstractDeployCommand.doDeploy(AbstractDeployCommand.java:116)
 at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.plugin.local.DistributeCommand.run(DistributeCommand.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.LifecycleException: load of com.ibm.developerworks/ticker/1.0/war failed
 at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.loadConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:327)
 at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.DeploymentConfigurationManager.loadConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationManager.java:115)
 at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.loadConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:286)
 at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.DeploymentConfigurationManager.loadConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationManager.java:111)
 at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.DeploymentContext.createTempConfiguration(DeploymentContext.java:146)
 ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.InvalidConfigException: Error starting configuration gbean com.ibm.developerworks/ticker/1.0/war
 at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.load(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:352)
 at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.DeploymentConfigurationManager.load(DeploymentConfigurationManager.java:119)
 at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.loadConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:312)
 ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.geronimo.kernel.repository.MissingDependencyException: Missing dependency: org.directwebremoting/dwr/2.0.3/jar
 at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.ConfigurationResolver.resolve(ConfigurationResolver.java:113)
 at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.Configuration.buildClassPath(Configuration.java:409)
 at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.Configuration.createConfigurationClasssLoader(Configuration.java:326)
 at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.Configuration.(Configuration.java:271)
 at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.load(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:348)
 ... 23 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

org.apache.geronimo.kernel.repository.MissingDependencyException: Missing dependency: org.directwebremoting/dwr/2.0.3/jar at

Looks like you are missing the DWR jar